# How does preCondition="managedHandler" work for modules?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

After reading some documentation about the integrated pipeline I'm confused about how IIS determines when to run managed modules, what a managed request actually is, and how that is determined, e.g.:

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-integration-with-iis
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/08/30/iis-7-0-asp-net-pipelines-modules-handlers-and-preconditions.aspx

"Managed" requests are mentioned several times. There's one instance where it is explained that a managed request is a request that has a mapping to a managed handler. There's also a quote saying that a handler is a "special" module (second link).

Modules are described as something that runs for *every* request and that a handler has a mapping that specifies when it should run (e.g. HTTP GET for *.aspx) (second and first links). Furthermore, for the modules the execute_request_handler [which I'm assuming as the point where the handler actually runs] comes after several stages of the pipeline (after begin_request, authenticate, authorize, etc...), it implies that there's a step that happens before all that, that establishes that the request is for a managed handler, so as to disable the execution of modules that have the preCondition="managedHanlder" when the request is not for a managed handler.

I feel there's something I'm missing here, can someone shed some light about how does preCondition="managedHandler" exactly works?

Answer (score 9):

From this blog post (http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2006/11/04/precondition-what.aspx) :

> ### The ManagedHandler precondition
>
> IIS 7.0 introduces a new managed
>   extensibility model. Handlers and Modules can now be written in
>   managed code and directly integrated into the IIS request pipeline.
>   But switching between managed and native code is an expensive
>   operation. The managedHandler precondition was introduced to allow
>   optimizing the performance of requests where no managed code needs to
>   be involved, for example when static files (.html, .jpg etc.) are
>   served. No managed code is called if the request is served by a native
>   handler and every managed module is configured with the managedHandler
>   precondition. A practical scenario is Forms authentication. The
>   managed Forms authentication module has a managedHandler precondition
>   and is therefore only called when ASP.NET content (e.g. *.aspx) pages
>   are requested. If a .html page is requested the forms authentication
>   is not called. If you want to protect all your content with forms
>   authentication you can simply remove the managedHandler precondition
>   from the Forms authentication module entry.

In short, if a request can be served by a native IIS module (say, an image for instance), it will not have to go through all the managed pipeline (for instance, all the "global.asax" events and even more), resulting in a huge performance gain.

**EDIT:** The actual answer to your question is : Handlers mappings. This is what associates a file extension to a specific handler. You will find below how to edit these mappings in II7. You can also find more information about handler mapping [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771240%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

[image: open this section in IIS]

[image: Then you will see all the registered mappings]

Comment: Thanks, but that does not really answer my question. If you look at iis pipeline it seems like the handler to be used is only determined after several steps (begin request, authenticate, authorize, map request handler,...). But, as you cited, if for example, you request an image those steps in a module with preConditions="managedHandler" will not be run (unless runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is true). So, how does this actually work? When is it determined that the request is for a managed handler? (it must be before those pipeline steps)

Comment: This is done via Handler mappings (you can access the mappings via the IIS management console - inetmgr.exe). This basically maps a file extension to a handler. You can find a detailed request lifecycle diagram at the following [link](http://bit.ly/1bZmt8g)

Comment: That might be true, in fact it makes perfect sense, however, none of the sources that I was able to find (and the ones that you added) explicitly says that. Namely that the first step when a request comes in is to determine which will be its handler.

Comment: Well, as shown by the diagram link I posted, the mapping to the handler is clearly not the first step. Maybe this [link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=747) will give you more information. Hope it helps, the request pipeline / lifecycle can be quite a complex workflow / state machine in IIS + ASP.NET.

Comment: As you point out, it is not portrayed as the first step. However, this simple exercise left me puzzled exactly because of that. Create a custom IHttpModule, have it register on the HttpApplication events and just log (I just wrote to a file on disk, for example, Begin Request was called, do this for every event). Register this module in web.config with preCondition="managedHandler". Continued...

Comment: Continued... Ensure that runAllManagedModulesForallRequests="false". Do a request for a .aspx page for example and verify that the request goes through all the stages (check the file that the custom module produces). Perform a request for an image. Verify that the module did not go through any of the stages. How can this be if the first step is not the mapping of the handler?

Comment: Because again, as shown on this [diagram](http://i1.iis.net/media/7187025/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing-496-rewrite%20diagram.gif?cdn_id=2013-07-03-001), right before the mapping, URL Rewriting, Authentication, Authorization and Cache resolving happens.

Comment: I don't think that's the whole story (in my experiment BeginRequest  for my managed module was not called when the req was for an image), which is consistent with the description of preCondition="managedHandler" modules only running for "managed requests". That BeginRequest (where URL rewriting happens, which by the way isn't just a module that handles begin request and rewrites the url?) is not called if it is in a managed module.
What I expected was that all module's stages, i.e. BeginRequest, Authenticate, authorize up until map handler would be called, but that is not the case.

Comment: You might be confusing the handler being called and the actual pipeline of IIS. The BeginRequest, Authenticate etc... are not part of the module, it is IIS events themselves. Then IIS maps the handlers and IF it is to be invoked (ie. managed handler), then it goes the handler.  

This is also a good article about it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/08/30/iis-7-0-asp-net-pipelines-modules-handlers-and-preconditions.aspx

Comment: They are IIS events themselves, that you can register withing a custom module, in fact that's the whole point of this discussion.  
If you look at the original post I had that link there, it was actually that article that I found unclear (also, it's in that article that a handler is described as a "special module". Haven't seen that anywhere else).

Comment: It all boils down to this: In integrated mode, if rammfar is off, and you have a request that maps to a managed handler the modules with preCondition="managedHandler" will run. 
If you request is for a native handler they won't.
The modules can register on an event for the several IIS stages (BeginRequest, Authenticat, etc).
So it seems that there's a first step that determines if the request is "managed" and starts that pipeline involving all modules, if not, only involve native modules.

Comment: If I use managedHandler precondition, should Global.Application_BeginRequest execute **before** my http module's Context_BeginRequest ?  Problem I'm having is my httpmodule is being executed first.

Comment: Nevermind, I switched to the context.PostAcquireRequestState and my handler executes after Application_BeginRequest now

Comment: @AaronLS I don't think that is correct, you can find the full list of events for the module here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=747. The PostAcquireRequestState event still happens before the execute handler (where Global.Application_BeginRequest should be running if I'm not mistaken). A safe bet would be PostRequestHandlerExecute.